# Transpose Pandas dataframe into data ranges

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to transpose the following table:

`Name | State | Value
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
nameA | state1 | 1 
nameA | state2 | 5 
nameA | state1 | 9 
nameA | state1 | 2 
nameB | state2 | 3 
nameB | state1 | 1`

into a table like this:

`Name | range1_state1  |range1_state2 | range2_state1 | range2_state2 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
nameA |      2        |        1      |       0       |       1
nameB |      1        |        0      |       1       |       0`

if range1 = [0, 5) and range2 = (5, 10]
and the data in the second table is the number of occurrences in
the first table.

Thank You

Comment: [Welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to Stack Overflow. Any code attempts ? It makes it bit easier to understand to answer. See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for bins with [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
print (pd.cut(df['Value'], bins=[0, 5, 10], include_lowest=True))
0     [0, 5]
1     [0, 5]
2    (5, 10]
3     [0, 5]
4     [0, 5]
5     [0, 5]
Name: Value, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [[0, 5] < (5, 10]]

df['rng'] = pd.cut(df['Value'], bins=[0, 5, 10], 
                   labels=['range1','range2'], include_lowest=True)
df['State'] = df['rng'].astype(str) + '_' + df['State']
print (df)
    Name          State  Value     rng
0  nameA  range1_state1      1  range1
1  nameA  range1_state2      5  range1
2  nameA  range2_state1      9  range2
3  nameA  range1_state1      2  range1
4  nameB  range1_state2      3  range1
5  nameB  range1_state1      1  range1

df = pd.crosstab(df.Name, df.State)
print (df)
State  range1_state1  range1_state2  range2_state1
Name                                              
nameA              2              1              1
nameB              1              1              0
```

EDIT:

You can check values where are binned in this sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Value':np.arange(11)})
df1['bins'] = pd.cut(df1['Value'], bins=[0, 5, 10], include_lowest=True)
print (df1)
    Value     bins
0       0   [0, 5]
1       1   [0, 5]
2       2   [0, 5]
3       3   [0, 5]
4       4   [0, 5]
5       5   [0, 5]
6       6  (5, 10]
7       7  (5, 10]
8       8  (5, 10]
9       9  (5, 10]
10     10  (5, 10]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This method changed my execution time from 6sec to 0.08 seconds :D

Comment: Yes, `cut` is really fast. Thank you for accepting!